# Testing with multinomial covariates

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, inference, biostatistics, multinomial-logit

I have a question about how to perform analysis and testing in this setup.

I have two groups of people, one group with healthy individuals and one group with infected individuals.

A questionnaire has been answered by all individuals, where they had to answer either:
A a lot,
B medium/high amount,
C medium/low amount,
D not at all.

The question could be: Do you drink water, or do you smoke.

Then when trying to bundle data, I'm not sure how to perform the analysis. I want to test for overall difference between the groups.

I have one idea.

I could count how many answered the different options within each question, and split upon group. But from thereon I'm not sure how to continue...

An example of how the data looks is like this
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
ID & Q1 & Q2 & \cdots \\
1 (healthy) & A & D & \cdots \\
2(healthy) & B & B & \cdots \\
3(infected & B & C & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
$$

I hope someone can help me.

My main goal is to test for difference between healthy and infected, and report som p-value from a test statistic.

Best

Comment: It sounds like your response variable (dependent variable) is the multinomial variable, not the covariates. (I'd even consider it ordinal.)

Comment: Good point @Dave ! Do you then think I should go with multinomial logistic regression or?

Comment: Since you probably have multiple questions, that complicates the matter, but if you only had one question, I would do an ordinal regression with the group (healthy vs infected) predicting the question response.

Comment: Yes but that's not the case. I need the know if the answers differ in general from healthy vs infected.

And also, I'm not sure if it's proper regression anyway, since there are only groups, and no numerical expression in the covariates. @Dave

Comment: It certainly is a regression, just a simple regression. In fact, the two-sample t-test can be expressed as a regression like this. Your case might be something like a multivariate ordinal regression.

Comment: What would be ordinal about the 0/1 response?

Comment: Sorry I deleted this comment
Maybe if i setup the dataset such as modeling a 0-1 response, as a function of the answers to the questions ? Then it'd probably be ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Well.. Nothing needs to be ordinal nescessarily?
I just need to be able to tell whether the overall difference is significant. And I need to treat the response to each question as a factor, not a numerical one. And then see if I can get inference when trying to model the probability of being infected as a function of this questionnaire.
It's just an idea.

Comment: Of coure if I make the bundling and have the count, then it is ordinal, that's correct. 
Sorry about me being sort of confused about this issue of treating this dataset.